# mkfs.vfat command not found

Tags: arch-linux, uefi

I was trying to run the command while installing Arch Linux

```
pacman -S grub efibootmgr
```

But, I forgot to format EFI(dev/sda5). So, I run following command

```
mkfs.vfat /dev/sda5
```

I am getting that `mkfs.vfat command not found` so, I tried

```
pacman -S dosfstools
```

This time I am getting that fails to commit transaction(invalid URL for server)

Comment: "_mkfd.vfat command not found_" is that because you mistyped `mkfs.vfat` or that you copied it wrongly in your question? "_fails to commit transaction"_ what's the precise error message (please do not paraphrase). [Edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/645762/edit) to fix both parts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I was having the issue I just face the issue when I run the command as a root user(arch-chroot). When I reboot my pc than tried the same thing again I noticed that it was working fine. I think I was having the issue cause, root user doesn't have access to run the code. There was lot of code which I couldn't run as root user.